# File Permissions Error on Moving File

Tags: c#

I am working on this program where it moves files from a server to another place on the server. An issues here is some of the files are read only. 
My idea to get around that was to change the files so they are not read only in order to copy them, then change them back to read only like they were before.

Problem with this here is that I am having an error now that I cannot even change the file permissions since only admin can change the permissions.

Any ideas of how to get around this?

Comment: Modify the share permissions? Connect and run the program under an account that has the admin permissions?

Comment: A lot of people will be using this so thats not exactly the solution. @crashmstr

Comment: If the user cannot do what the program is trying to do, then how can you expect to do it with a program? If you can't change this, you might need to run this directly on the server instead of through the network share.